# Oil furnace keeps locking out

Tags: furnace, boiler, troubleshooting

My oil furnace keeps locking out on a daily basis. The reset button causes it to start, but within a day it always locks out again, usually overnight.

The boiler is a Buderus and the burner is a Riello.

The boiler has been cleaned twice.

**What are the detailed steps to find the source of the problem?**

Comment: What does "lock out" mean? What model numbers are involved? Have links to the instruction manuals?

Comment: Does the water pressure drop?

Comment: @SolarMike No no

Comment: Sounds like the fuel flow could be inadequate. Or, the burners are dirty? Or, it's not getting enough fresh air to fuel the fire? Does it give a fault code? Considering your expectation of a perfect answer, you've really provided very little detail about your situation. Did you even Google "oil furnace lockout"?

Comment: I assume you've attempted none of the steps found here? https://actionac.net/2020/10/05/what-ignition-lockout-mean-causes-hard-soft-how-fix/

Comment: If you don't have a "smart" burner control that will tell you why it locked out, you have to check (or have someone check) everything that might affect that - transformer/igniter, flame sensor, flame sensor window, fuel/air mixture if it's sooting up the flame sensor window, fuel pressure, change the nozzle or clean the nozzle.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I know that. Let me repeat my question: WHAT ARE THE DETAILED STEPS TO FIND THE SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM. Do you even read the question before making comments? Try reading more than the title of the question.

Comment: I would not give "DETAILED STEPS" as I have no way of knowing you level of competence to deal with something that can explode.

Comment: Was not an answer as it was submitted in the Comments section…

Comment: @TylerDurden As with most things in life, this is going to be a process of elimination. Create a list of common lockout causes and eliminate them one-by-one. Given your reputation I am amazed that you think your question is up to par.

Comment: Since your profile states: `People who irk me: Nannies that lecture me about safety. I notice that it is usually the ones who have no idea how to solve problems that like to go around prattling about safety.` and is a _public_ forum where _you_ are not the only person who reads and potentially takes action on the answers provided, maybe this isn't the best place for you to ask this question. A strong tendency to answer questions with the _strictest_ sense of safety has evolved here because it it human nature to shortcut safety suggestions, and nobody here wants to be responsible (con't)

Comment: ...for someone getting injured due to unsafe recommendations. If _you_ choose to ignore safety protocols given, that's entirely up to you and you are free to do so. However, if they're not shared, and the next person _doesn't even know what the safety protocols are_ then we are responsible (morally, at least), for any injuries. **That** is why people go "prattling on about safety".

Answer (score 3):

> 2021 Massachusetts General Laws
> Part I - Administration of the Government
> Title XX - Public Safety and Good Order
> Chapter 148 - Fire Prevention
> Section 10c - Alteration, Repair or Installation of Oil Burners; Necessity of Certificate; Exceptions
>
> Universal Citation: MA Gen L ch 148 § 10c (2021)
> Section 10C. No person shall alter, repair or install any oil burning equipment or any of the appurtenances thereto, except for electrical wiring and connections, as defined by rules and regulations promulgated under the provisions of section ten governing the construction, installation and operation of oil burning equipment and the keeping, storage and use of fuel oil or other inflammable products used in connection therewith, unless he holds a certificate granted by an examiner for the certification of oil burner technicians. Notwithstanding the provisions of the preceding sentence, the cleaning of an oil burner strainer or nozzle or the cleaning or replacement of a photo cell, in any building or structure by the owner or manager thereof or by any regular employee of such owner or manager in a building or structure owned or managed by his employer, may be done without the holding by such owner, manager or employee of a certificate as an oil burner technician.

So, you may clean the strainer or nozzle, clean or replace the photocell, or do that thing we know you hate to hear from meta, or break the law in your state. Well, actually, since you hate that thing so much, you could always apply for an oil burner technician license.

Comment: Well then, a lit wick and puddle of oil dripping on the floor ought to keep the house warm. Just adjust the valve to keep the dripping rate right.